# Is there anyway i can view the asterisk mobile number on Webpages?

Tags: html

Hi i wanted to ask that is thee any possible way in which i can preview the asterisk codes written on webpages(note: not the password box) in the web format page which has a mobile phone number written in asterisk code. Like as the follow

```
[ p class="description ph-num-description medium">
                            &lrm;(•••) •••-••48
    </p> ]
```

Comment: Where is that code coming from?

Comment: That code is from Apple Webpage

Comment: @NicoHaase I wanted to unlocked my Apple Account. But since it got locked i need to provide my trusted phone number which i do not remember that is was i was wondering if there is a way to view the asterisk code of phone number.

Comment: No, you can't. apple send you num without digits.

Comment: If that is the HTML sent to the browser, that is all you have. There is no other information hidden in those dots.